# Setting same animation to many Buttons

Tags: android, animation, button

I am using custom animations at `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP` events of my button.
However, right now, I am manually setting `OnTouchListener` to each `Button` manually with code like this:

```
    myButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View yourButton, MotionEvent theMotion) {
            Animation animation;
            switch (theMotion.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(NickNameScreenActivity.this, R.anim.button_down);
                    myButton.startAnimation(animation);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(NickNameScreenActivity.this, R.anim.button_up);
                    myButton.startAnimation(animation);
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This is cumbersome as I have to repeat this for all Buttons.

Is there a way to set it automatically for all buttons or a tidy XML way of doing this?

Comment: How about refactoring the anonymous class into an inner class extending the `View.OnTouchListener` class and using it for all Buttons?

Comment: Thank you, it is a good idea. It seems I can't avoid creating a variable for each button in this case.

Comment: Then how about writing a custom view extending `Button` and use it in xml? Maybe you can replace `NickNameScreenActivity.this` with `getContext()`.

Comment: Thank you, please post the second as an answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom view extending `Button` and use it in xml. Maybe you can replace `NickNameScreenActivity.this` with `getContext()`.